# using social django package login as google showing url missmatch?

Tags: django

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8000/^oauth/complete/google-oauth2/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/300857016299-omtn7s93vsuml8f3ja0v0aiacr41e4sf.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=300857016299

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login:log'
LOGOUT_URL = 'login:logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login:success'
```

Comment: These settings need to be actual URLs, not names of URL patterns.

Answer (score 0):

In the urls.py  changed the regex as: 
from:

```
 path('^oauth/',include('social_django.urls',namespace='social')),
```

to:

```
 path('oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
```

The problem solved.